# Check 4 strings if there are duplicates

Tags: python, python-2.7

s1, s2, s3, s4 have a string as content

I want to do something like this

```
if one or more is the same s1, s2, s3 or s4:
    print error
else
    print s1, s2, s3, s4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a set:

```
if len(set([s1, s2, s3, s4])) != 4:
    pass # not all unique
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to check if all strings are different:

```
4 == len(set([s1, s2, s3, s4]))
```